# Can Azure VM snapshots be deleted safely?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, snapshot, azure-virtual-machine

I used CloudXplorer to create a snapshot on the VHD of a VM I was doing some installs on.  The installs went okay, so is it okay to delete the snapshots or do I need to somehow merge them in to ensure I can backup my current VM state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snapshots are just a point-in-time representation of a blob (in your case, a page blob storing your vhd). It's read-only, and it's disposable. If a page in the vhd's page blob is changed, then a new page is created for the snapshot, to represent the original state of the blob. Once you delete the snapshot, the list of pages, along with any created pages to preserve the snapshot's state, are deleted (and with no impact on the original blob).

Note that you won't be able to delete the original blob until you first delete all of its snapshots (and you can also delete blob+snapshots at once).

Comment: Thanks so much, David! Since it sounds like you're much more knowledgeable about this, a follow on question if you would.  If I want to continue to be safe about saving my working VM state as I proceed to configure and install more, would you recommend I take snapshots, copy the VHD to backup container, or both (I believe the VHD copy doubles the storage I'm paying for)?

Comment: @BurntOC So, that means once if I created snapshots in Azure, later I created clones of it. Now if I don't need the snapshots anymore. Will deletion of these snapshots affect the clones that I created using them?

Comment: @RavishRawat - didn't you just ask this as a posted question (I posted a comment asking for clarification of your term "clone")? In any case: please don't post new questions as comments under an answer, especially to posts that are 4 years old (as is this one). Much better to post a new question (and reference this particular question / answer in your new question).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yes, I deleted the question because someone downvoted it for some reason. Many times I have seen people just downvoting and not providing a solution. So, I asked it here.